# PHP nested foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, nested

So basically I want to show the second foreach loop items at every item in the first foreachloop, but now it only shows at the first item of the first foreach loop instead of every item in the foreach loop.

My variables:

```html
        /* Queries */
$categories = $conn->query('SELECT pc.name, pc.ID, COUNT(p.id) AS amount FROM productcategory AS pc INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.categoryID = pc.ID WHERE p.available = 1 GROUP BY pc.ID');
$categories->execute();

$subcategories = $conn->query('SELECT pcs.name, pcs.categoryID, pcs.ID FROM productsubcategory AS pcs GROUP BY pcs.ID');
$subcategories->execute();
```

```html
foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        if(isset($_GET['categorie'])) {
                            if($category["name"] === $_GET['categorie']) {
                                $class = 'class="selected"';
                            } else {
                                $class = '';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="?categorie=<?php echo $category["name"]; ?>" <?php echo $class; ?>> <?php echo $category["name"] . ' ('. $category["amount"] .')'; ?></a></li>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                            if($subcategory['categoryID'] == $category['ID']) {
                                ?>
                                <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=<?php echo $subcategory["name"]; ?>" <?php echo $class; ?>> <?php echo $subcategory["name"]; ?></a></li>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Output

```css
.sub-cat {
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
                                        <li><a href="?categorie=Koffie"> Koffie (2)</a></li>
                                                        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=extra sterk"> extra sterk</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Sterk"> Sterk</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Zoete"> Zoete</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Zoete"> Zoete</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Zoete"> Zoete</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Honing"> Honing</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Honing"> Honing</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Bon bons"> Bon bons</a></li>
                                                            <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Puur"> Puur</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="?categorie=Thee"> Thee (4)</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="?categorie=Chocolade"> Chocolade (2)</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="?categorie=Olie"> Olie (1)</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="?categorie=Wijn"> Wijn (2)</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="?categorie=Accessoires"> Accessoires (2)</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="?categorie=Cadeaus"> Cadeaus (1)</a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

Expected output:
So basicly i want to show the good sub category at the right category. I know I need to use a if statement to compare if subcategory category ID is the same as category ID, but the second loop stops and the first element of the first loop.

```css
.sub-cat {
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Koffie"> Koffie (2)</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=extrasterk"> extra sterk</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="categorie=Sterk"> Sterk</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Thee"> Thee (4)</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Zoete"> Zoete</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Zoete"> Zoete</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Zoete"> Zoete</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Honing"> Honing</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Honing"> Honing</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Chocolade"> Chocolade (2)</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Bon bons"> Bon bons</a></li>
    <li class="sub-cat"><a href="?categorie=Puur"> Puur</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Olie"> Olie (1)</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Wijn"> Wijn (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Accessoires"> Accessoires (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categorie=Cadeaus"> Cadeaus (1)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're getting now and the output you were expecting?

Comment: where do you set `$subcategories`?

Comment: What? How many category variables do you have? Please post your variables

Comment: Bit of a long-shot, but are you sure these aren't being hidden on the client-side? Can you post the actual source this is generating rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Added some examples and extra code.

Comment: you need to group/sort the subcategories by (parent-) category somehow. Now you just loop through all of the subs without any connection/reference.

Comment: @Pieter can you please post the output of the variables and the structure of the 2 tables as well? thanks

Comment: If you want all the subcategories to show up for all the categories, this should work fine. With this code, I'm not sure how you're getting the output you're getting: https://eval.in/931133

Comment: @iainn The output of your link is the output I want to have, if you take a look at https://pieter.plantagedevelopment.nl/shop it stops at the first element of the first loop.

Comment: @Pieter What I'm saying is that there must be something else going on. The code in my link is identical to yours. If you're getting different output, then something else is manipulating the output before it reaches the user.

Comment: @iainn the problem is, if I copy your code to my own website it works aswell. It is a very strange thing I can't figure out why it doesn't loop further then the first element.